# Calculate conditional in line feature using an expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, field-calculator, syntax

I'm trying to calculate a conditional in a line feature but I can't see were my sintax is wrong. Could you guys help me?

```
def Reclass(TIPO_PAV):
    if TIPO_PAV=='TERRA':
        return !shape.length@kilometers! /40*60
    if TIPO_PAV=='ASFALTO': 
        return  !shape.length@kilometers!
    else:
        return 0
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You should specify the field within the function in the execute window.  You can't just put the field in parenthesis.

```
def Reclass(field):
    if field =='TERRA':
        return !shape.length@kilometers! /40*60
    if field =='ASFALTO': 
        return !shape.length@kilometers!
    else:
        return 0
```

[image]

Comment: OK ..I dit it now but stil not working.

Comment: The error is point to line where are the expression !shape.length@kilometers!

Comment: Pass !shape! To def as well